# How to extract the length of the input string of bash shell program?

Tags: bash, shell

Here are the code in

```
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
echo ${#$1}
echo ${#file}
length=${#file}
```

my input in the shell are test.sh

```
line 6: ${#$1}: bad substitution
```

So how can I print length of my input and assigned as a variable in bash shell program for subsequently use?

Comment: Shouldn't file=$1 and not the other way round as you have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is, that in the line `$1=file`, the `$1` gets expanded to your first argument and this is run as a command.
So if you run your script with the argument `good`, bash will run the command `good=file` which is just wrong.

The solution is obviously to get the assignment right:

```sh
file=$1
```

Also, your `${#$1}` gets a bit much of special characters. Like `${#file}` the string after the `#` is the variable name, which in the case of arguments is just a number, so it should be `${#1}` instead.

In general, I find complex parameter substitution with arguments quite horrible to read (and in the case of arithmetic expressions they are of coruse quite impossible), so I tend to always assign properly named variables to them (so I use `x=$1; echo ${x}` rather than `echo $1`)

After that, your script does what it is supposed to do:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
echo ${#1}
echo ${#file}
length=${#file}
echo "length: ${length}"
```